# Jira Python session() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, jira

I am trying to load data from JIRA using jira for python, however it keeps me failing with message:

```
session() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Here is my code:

```py
from jira import JIRA
options = {"server": ""}

username=''
password=''

jira = JIRA(options, auth=(username, password))

issue = jira.issue('')
print(issue)
```

Nothing complex, simple stuff, and full traceback here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{{path}}/my_script.py", line 9, in <module>
    jira = JIRA(options, auth=(user, password))
  File "{{path}}/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 496, in __init__
    user = self.session()
  File "{{path}}/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 2980, in session
    r = self._session.get(url)
  File "{{path}}/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 172, in get
    return self.__verb("GET", url, **kwargs)
  File "{{path}}/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 143, in __verb
    response = method(url, timeout=self.timeout, **kwargs)
  File "{{path}}/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "{{path}}/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "{{path}}/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 662, in send
    r = dispatch_hook('response', hooks, r, **kwargs)
  File "{{path}}/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/hooks.py", line 31, in dispatch_hook
    _hook_data = hook(hook_data, **kwargs)
  File "{{path}}/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 199, in handle_401
    self.init_session()
  File "{{path}}/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 215, in init_session
    self.start_session()
  File "{{path}}/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 229, in start_session
    self._get_session(self.__auth)
TypeError: session() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: What package exactly are you using…?

Comment: This one: https://pypi.org/project/jira/

Answer (score 6):

I think you want to use `basic_auth` instead of `auth`. That's what I found from reading the docs (https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#jira).

> basic_auth – A tuple of username and password to use when establishing a session via HTTP BASIC authentication.

```
jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=(username, password))
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, basic_auth will not work for me

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, there is an issue with the latest version (3.0.1).
When I downgraded to 3.0a1 it works just fine

Comment: Then it would be a good decision to file an issue on their github page, so it may be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known JIRA issue [1035](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/issues/1035). I'd suggest pinning the version to `2.0.0` in the package version file (or whatever version that works with your dependencies) until the issue gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using (3.0.1)

The code below just works for me.

```
from jira import JIRA
from jira.exceptions import JIRAError

try:
    jira = JIRA(server='https://xxx.xxx.com', basic_auth=(userName, pasword))
except JIRAError as e:
    if e.status_code == 401:
        print(e)
    elif e.status_code == 403:
        print(" !!! 403 !!!")
        print(e)
    else:
        print(e)
    exit(-1)

issue = jira.issue('MyProject-24')
print(issue.fields.summary)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this issue is in jira==3.0.1 and that jira==3.1.1 fixes this issue